# Set initial dropdown value to viewmodel

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm having some issues with a dropdown list where I need to pass the initial value to the viewmodel. Just to clarify: I'm working on an edit-form, so the dropdownlist will be populated with an already-selected value.

What I have so far is:

Razor:

```html
<select data-bind="selectedOptions: selectedLength"> 
// razor code omitted 
foreach(var preValue in lengthPreValues) 
{ 
   if(lengthPreValues.Contains(preValue.value)) 
   { 
      <option selected="selected" value='@preValue'>@preValue</ option> 
   } 
  else 
  { 
     <option value='@preValue'>@preValue</option> 
  } 
}
```

And my viewmodel looks like this:

```
var editOfferViewModel = { 
  // Properties omitted 
  selectedLength: ko.observable("") 
}; 

ko.applyBindings(editOfferViewModel);
```

While this definately works when selecting a new value, I'm a bit stuck when it comes to setting the initial value. I was fortunate enough to get some great help from Ryan Niemeyer here on stackoverflow.com with checkboxes and creating custom bindinghandlers, but I'm still 
having a hard time to figure it out to be honest.

So, any help and/or hint on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common and easy way to do this is to serialize your model values to the page.  This would be something like:

```
var viewModel = {
  choices: ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Options))),
  selectedChoices: ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(SelectedOptions)))
};
```

Then, just use a standard data-bind on your select like:

```
data-bind="options: choices, selectedOptions: selectedChoices"
```

You then don't even need to populate the option elements in Razor.

If your `viewModel` is built in an external file, then you can just set the value of the observables in your view (after your external script has been loaded)

Answer (score 2):

My data is something like :

```
dataList = [ {name:'length1',id:1},{name:'length2',id:2},{name:'length3',id:3},{name:'length4',id:4},{name:'length5',id:5} ]
```

And I have been using that data with dropdown like this :

```
<select name="xxx" id="xxxid" data-bind="options: dataList,  value: selectedLength , optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Please Select...'"></select>


<select name="xxx2" id="xxxid2" data-bind="options: dataList,  selectedOptions: multiSelectedLength , optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', optionsCaption: 'Please Select...'" size="5" multiple="true"></select>   

var editOfferViewModel = {
 selectedLength: ko.observable(),
 multiSelectedLength: ko.observableArray()    
};

ko.applyBindings(editOfferViewModel);

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Set initial value
    editOfferViewModel.selectedLength(2);
    // Set inital multi value
    editOfferViewModel.multiSelectedLength(['2','3']);   
});
```

You can use value property to set initial value.

Here is the working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gurkavcu/kKNtv/).