# KnockoutJS : how to set the initial value from a dropdown list when data is retrieved asynchronously using JSON?

Tags: json, drop-down-menu, asynchronous, knockout.js

Issue is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386316/knockoutjs-initial-values-are-not-posted-to-server-when-using-ko-tojsonthis) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753595/set-initial-dropdown-value-to-viewmodel-knockoutjs).

The problem is that when a options list is not yet populated with valid data (because the JSON call return is asynchronously), you cannot set the initial selected value.

```
function PersonViewModel() {
    // Data members
    this.Function_Id = ko.observable('@(Model.Function_Id)');
    this.Functions = ko.observableArray([{ Id: '@(Model.Function_Id)', Name: ''}]); // This works
    //this.Functions = ko.observableArray(); // This does not work
    this.SubFunctions = ko.observableArray();

    this.GetFunctions = function () {
        var vm = this;

        $.getJSON(
            '@Url.Action("GetFunctions", "Function")',
            function (data) {
                vm.Functions(data);
                if (vm.Function_Id() === undefined) {
                    //vm.Function_Id('@(Model.Function_Id)'); // Only way to solve my problem?
                }
            }
        );
    };
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var personViewModel = new PersonViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(personViewModel);

    personViewModel.GetFunctions();
});
```

See this modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agjEF/)

Comment: Typically, you would populate your array with the current matching value (as you are doing), then set the actual values after your AJAX call (as you are doing).  Is your scenario that the currently selected choice is actually not in the list when the actual items are returned?  Can you reproduce your client-side scenario from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Beban/

Comment: When the items are returned, the selected choice IS in the list, so no problem there.

I just find it strange that I need to provide a fake value to the ko.observableArray, just as you do in your example.

Comment: The value binding enforces that the selected value is actually in your options.  The first time that it is bound this would not be true.  The other options are to either call applyBindings later (usually not desirable) or set the "selected" observables value later (which looks like what you were getting at in your success funciton).

Comment: Isn't there a DataLoaded event on an observableArray which can be used?

Comment: You can use a manual subscription on an observable/observableArray/dependentObservable to run code when the value changes.  You would do:
    `vm.Functions.subscribe(function() {
        //run your code here
    }, vm); //"this" set to vm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to 'RP Niemeyer' and 'Sandeep G B', I've created [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/stefh/vGRLF/).

Maybe it's also an idea to add an 'initialValue' property to the data-bind functionality for a the data-bind attribute from a select like this:

```
<select id="Function_Id"
    data-bind='
        options: Functions,
        optionsValue : "Id",
        optionsText: "Name",
        initialValue = 1,
        value: Function_Id,
        optionsCaption: Functions().length == 0 ? "Loading..." : "--NONE--"'>
</select>
```

Comment: You marked your own answer correct and it doesn't work in your own fiddle.  Sandeep's solution still works.  I'd change the correct answer to his.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function Item(id, name) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
}

var viewModel = {
    selectedItem: ko.observable(),
    //items: ko.observableArray([new Item(3, "")])
    items: ko.observableArray()
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
var selectedIndex = 3;
setTimeout(function() {

    viewModel.items([
        new Item(1, "pencil"),
        new Item(2, "pen"),
        new Item(3, "marker"),
        new Item(4, "crayon")
        ]);
    var selectedValue;
    $.each(viewModel.items(), function(index, item) {
        if (index === selectedIndex) {
            selectedValue = item;
        }
    });
    viewModel.selectedItem(selectedValue);
}, 1000);
```

```css
h2 { font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: items, optionsText: 'name', value: selectedItem"><option selected="selected"></option></select>
<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
```